# query for associated fields (many to many realtion) with arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, arel

I have a many to many relation like this :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :letter_trackings
end
```

and

```
class LetterTracking < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :assignees, class_name: "User"
end
```

I want to use arel to search in assignees like this :

```
users = User.arel_table
letter_trackings = LetterTracking.arel_table

@users = User.where(users[:name].matches("%#{Afsane Fadaei}%"))
@assignees_ids = @users.pluck(:id).uniq
letters_query = letter_trackings[:assignees].in(@assignees_ids)
@letter_trackings = LetterTracking.where(letters_query)
```

but it returns this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: letter_trackings.assignees: SELECT "letter_trackings".* FROM "letter_trackings" WHERE "letter_trackings"."assignees" IN (1189)):
```

That's because I don't know how to query **associated** (many to many) column in **arel**.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to use `arel` and a Rails query with `joins` and `where`?

Comment: @spickermann cause I have a search api and I store all the queries in a variable together then I find the whole search result.by the way I want to search in the whole model (table) not a specific record. Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: If it is "One to many" why are you using `has_and_belongs_to_many`? That for many to many relationships.

Comment: Oh God I've made a mistake Your so so right its many to many relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grab join table used to create HABTM association and search assignee_id or user_id for querying assignees in letter tracking. You can take following snippet for reference. I assumed that join table was LetterTrackingUsers.

```
letter_trackings = LetterTracking.arel_table
letter_trackings_users = LetterTrackingUsers.arel_table # here use HABTM table used by you for joining users and letter_trackings

query = letter_trackings_users[:user_id].in(@assignees_ids)  
or 
query = letter_trackings_users[:assignee_id].in(@assignees_ids)

@letter_trackings = LetterTracking.where(letters_query)
```

Comment: I have tried this it doesn't make sense. NameError: uninitialized constant LetterTrackingsUsers (this is my jointable name)

Comment: LetterTrackingsUsers should be model name. If you haven't created model for join table, then alternatively you can use Arel::Table.new(:name_of_join_table)

Comment: Still have the issue although I managed to make arel table for my join table

Comment: this is the error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: letter_trackings_users.assignee_id: SELECT "letter_trackings".* FROM "letter_trackings" WHERE "letter_trackings_users"."assignee_id" IN (5213)

Comment: you might have used user_id instead of assignee_id or some other name?